# Spring Bean representation with java class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring framework. I have a java class called `ConnectionFactory` and I need to add this as a spring bean. It has two properties `hostname` and `port` and I have successfully added as follows.

```
<bean class="com.xxx.xxx.ConnectionFactory">
                <property name="hostName" value="192.16.32.45"/>
                <property name="port" value="1418"/>

                ..........................
            </bean>
```

This class also contains a method call `createConnection(String username, String password)`. I need to pass values for username and password via this bean. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you considered using Component, PostConstruct and Value annotations do configure your spring container?

Answer (score 0):

you can add

```
<bean id="conFactory" class="com.xxx.xxx.ConnectionFactory" />
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject">
        <ref local="conFactory"/>
    </property>
    <property name="targetMethod">
        <value>createConnection</value>
    </property>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>username</value>
            <value>password</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have hostname and port you shoud use `init-method="init"` method like this:

```
   <bean id="connectionFactory" class="com.xxx.xxx.ConnectionFactory" init-method="init">
            <property name="hostName" value="192.16.32.45"/>
            <property name="port" value="1418"/>

            ..........................
        </bean>
```

And retrive data in class like:

```
   public class YourClass
   {
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory ;
     public void init() { ... } // Loads a configuration

      // Getters and setters
    }
```